# Javascript difference between onChange and onSubmit

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am testing out using ajax and came across an issue using onSubmit in the form vs. onChange in the form element. If I call the ajax request using the onSubmit method I am getting a status response of 0 and no text response.

The page calling the ajax request using onSubmit:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){                
            document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                            alert(ajaxRequest.status);
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "serverTime.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    return false;
}

</script>

<form name='myForm' onsubmit="ajaxFunction();">
Name: <input type='text'  name='username' /> <br />
Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
<input type="submit" id="submitTask" value="Get Time">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However if I call the ajax request using onChange the status response is 200 and the Time field populates.
The page calling the ajax request using onChange:

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            document.myForm.time.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                            alert(ajaxRequest.status);
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "serverTime.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    return false;
}

</script>

<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' onchange="ajaxFunction();" name='username' /> <br />
Time: <input type='text' name='time' />
<input type="submit" id="submitTask" value="Get Time">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ServerTime.php:

```
<?php
echo "test";//date("H:i:s"); 
?>
```

I was wondering what the difference is between the way the onsubmit and the onchange are handled and why this issue would be occuring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: onSubmit triggers when you click the submit button, onChange triggers when you change anything in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the difference is that `submit` changes the `location` of the page, and so cancels any ongoing AJAX requests. They therefore return with an error and a status of `0` (i.e. no response from the server).

You do `return false` in your function, presumably in an attempt to prevent the default form action. This doesn't work, because you need to `return false` from the handler itself. This means either in the `onsubmit` attribute itself, or by attaching the handler in a different way:

**`onsubmit`**

```
<form name='myForm' onsubmit="ajaxFunction();return false;">
```

**Attaching the handler with Javascript**

```
// inside your <script> tags
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByName('myForm')[0].onsubmit = ajaxFunction;
};
```

In this second case (which is better: it's normally better not to have Javascript in `on*` attributes), the `ajaxFunction` function is attached as the event handler, and the `return` value of that function is used to determine whether the default event proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

onchange event will only be triggered when u are clicking on the submit button.on the other hand consider an example of drop down list u can trigger an event whenever anybody changes the option from the list.i hope u r getting wat i am saying.if any doubt please let me know.

```
<select id="ss">
<option onchange="change()" value="1">v</option>
<option onchange="change()" value="2">c</option>
<option onchange="change()" value="22">d</option>
</select>
```

so in the above dropdownlist whenever options are changed the change() function will be called.
for onsubmit explanation and example go to the following link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp